# How to make pi ip address available by hostname on wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

I have a Raspberry Pi I'm going to use to control decorative lights
on my house, and have it be headless.  I'll want to be able to ssh
into the Pi to troubleshoot and monitor.  It connects on WiFi via
an AirPort Extreme.  While I could always go to the AirPort extreme
via the AirPort utility to find it's IP address (currently 10.0.1.12),
it would be more satisfying to have a hostname I could use.  I'm
currently puzzled, when I do 'dig raspberrypi' (from my Macintosh)
I get an address of 198.105.244.114 (Full output below).This doesn't
match anything on my pi.  Using 'ifconfig' on the pi shows no ip4
address associated with eth0, and the wlan0 address is on the
10.x.x.x network.  (Full output below as well).

What might I do to get the hostname 'raspberrypi' associated with 
the correct ip address which presumably can be different every time
power cycles on the Pi as it gets the address via DHCP on the Airport
extreme?  So I can then 'ssh raspberrypi' and get to the right place.

As I was preparing this question, I thought I'd change my pi hostname
just to look at the effects.  After pi reboot, it comes up with the
new hostname and the same wan0 address, but in the AirPortExtreme
display, the name doesn't change.  (Still 'raspberrypi' not the new
name 'lightpi'.  This is puzzling and annoying, but perhaps not
relevant.

As I was browsing the AirPort utility it occurred to me that I could
configure a DHCP reservation for the Pi, so I could use the same
IPv4 address all the time.  Would this be a reasonable alternative?

```
$ dig raspberrypi

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> raspberrypi
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 679
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;raspberrypi.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
raspberrypi.        10  IN  A   198.105.244.114
raspberrypi.        10  IN  A   198.105.254.114

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 02 11:22:57 PDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
o

pi@raspberrypi $ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ce:48:f9
          inet6 addr: fe80::d793:ec86:c0b:5b12/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:11472 (11.2 KiB)  TX bytes:11472 (11.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:59:ca:a4
          inet addr:10.0.1.12  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe59:caa4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7629 errors:0 dropped:153 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3990719 (3.8 MiB)  TX bytes:571886 (558.4 KiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do:

1. The DHCP reservation you mentioned would keep the IP address consistent, but in my experience has mixed results with consumer-grade routers.
2. You can change the router's DHCP range (IP addresses it's permitted to assign) and then have the pi configured with a static IP. This has always worked for me although I've only done it for PCs and printers.

I recommend #2 personally.